# Getting the ELF header of the main executable

Tags: c++, c, linux, elf

For various purposes, I am trying to obtain the address of the ELF header of the main executable without parsing `/proc/self/maps`. I have tried parsing the `link_list` chain given by `dlopen`/`dlinfo` functions but they do not contain an entry where `l_addr` points to the base address of the main executable. Is there any way to do this (Standard or not) without parsing `/proc/self/maps`?

An example of what I'm trying to do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <elf.h>
int main()
{
    Elf32_Ehdr* header = /* Somehow obtain the address of the ELF header of this program */;
    printf("%p\n", header);
    /* Read the header and do stuff, etc */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `read()` from `/proc/self/exe`

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention, I also need the base address along with the ELF header, and the ELF header should be where the base address is

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `void *` pointer returned by `dlopen(0, RTLD_LAZY)` gives you a `struct link_map *`, that corresponds to the main executable.

Calling `dl_iterate_phdr` also returns the entry for the main executable on the *very first* execution of callback.

You are likely confused by the fact that `.l_addr == 0` in the link map, and that `dlpi_addr == 0` when using `dl_iterate_phdr`.

This is happening, because `l_addr` (and `dlpi_addr`) don't actually record the load address of an ELF image. Rather, they record the *relocation* that has been applied to that image.

Usually the main executable is built to load at `0x400000` (for x86_64 Linux) or at `0x08048000` (for ix86 Linux), and are loaded at that same address (i.e. they are not relocated).

But if you link your executable with `-pie` flag, then it will be linked-at `0x0`, *and it will be relocated* to some other address.

So how do you get to the ELF header?

**2023 Update:**

> Isn't a simpler method (if relying on undocumented details), just to call `dladdr` on the `l_ld` address in the `struct link_map`, and then use `dli_fbase` out of that? – Simon Kissane

Indeed it is. Here is much simpler solution:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <link.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  void *dyn = _DYNAMIC;
  Dl_info info;
  if (dladdr(dyn, &info) != 0) {
    printf("a.out loaded at %p\n", info.dli_fbase);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra x.c -ldl && ./a.out
a.out loaded at 0x556433ea0000  # high address here because my GCC defaults to PIE.

gcc -g -Wall -Wextra x.c -ldl -no-pie && ./a.out
a.out loaded at 0x400000

gcc -g -Wall -Wextra x.c -ldl -no-pie -m32 && ./a.out
a.out loaded at 0x8048000
```

Original 2012 solution:

```
#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#endif

#include <link.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int
callback(struct dl_phdr_info *info, size_t size, void *data)
{
  int j;
  static int once = 0;

  if (once) return 0;
  once = 1;

  printf("relocation: 0x%lx\n", (long)info->dlpi_addr);

  for (j = 0; j < info->dlpi_phnum; j++) {
    if (info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_type == PT_LOAD) {
      printf("a.out loaded at %p\n",
             (void *) (info->dlpi_addr + info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_vaddr));
      break;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  dl_iterate_phdr(callback, NULL);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

    
$ gcc -m32 t.c && ./a.out
relocation: 0x0
a.out loaded at 0x8048000

$ gcc -m64 t.c && ./a.out
relocation: 0x0
a.out loaded at 0x400000

$ gcc -m32 -pie -fPIC t.c && ./a.out
relocation: 0xf7789000
a.out loaded at 0xf7789000

$ gcc -m64 -pie -fPIC t.c && ./a.out
relocation: 0x7f3824964000
a.out loaded at 0x7f3824964000
```

Update:

> Why does the man page say "base address" and not relocation?

It's a bug ;-)

I am guessing that the man page was written long before `prelink` and `pie`, and `ASLR` existed. Without prelink, shared libraries are always linked to load at address `0x0`, and then `relocation` and `base address` become one and the same.

> how come dlpi_name points to an empty string when info refers to the main executable?

It's an accident of implementation.

The way this works, is that the kernel `open(2)`s the executable and passes the open file descriptor to the loader (in the `auxv[]` vector, as `AT_EXECFD`). *Everything* the loader knows about the executable it gets by reading that file descriptor.

There is no easy way on UNIX to map a file descriptor back to the name it was opened as. For one thing, UNIX supports hard-links, and there could be multiple filenames that refer to the same file.

Newer Linux kernels also pass in the name that was used to `execve(2)` the executable (also in `auxv[]`, as `AT_EXECFN`). But that is optional, and even when it is passed in, glibc doesn't put it into `.l_name` / `dlpi_name` in order to not break existing programs which became dependent on the name being empty.

Instead, glibc saves that name in `__progname` and `__progname_full`.

The loader *coud* `readlink(2)` the name from `/proc/self/exe` on systems that didn't use `AT_EXECFN`, but the `/proc` file system is not guaranteed to be mounted either, so that would still leave it with an empty name sometimes.

Comment: Yea I guess I was confused then. But I'm wondering, where in the manpage says that `l_addr` or `dlpi_addr` is the relocated address? All the manpages I've read just says "base address"

Comment: Also, how come `dlpi_name` points to an empty string when `info` refers to the main executable? Shouldn't it contain the name of the main executable?

Comment: I've updated the answer. You get 3 answers for the price of 1 ;-)

Comment: Isn't a simpler method (if relying on undocumented details), just to call `dladdr` on the `l_ld` address in the `struct link_map`, and then use `dli_fbase` out of that?

Answer (score 1):

There is the glibc dl_iterate_phdr() function. I'm not sure it gives you exactly what you want, but that is as close as I know:

"The dl_iterate_phdr() function allows an application to inquire at run time to find out which shared objects it has loaded."
http://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr

Comment: It gets all the shared objects that the program has loaded, which I can already do by going through the link_list chain, and that is probably what it does in the function. But I want the base address of the application itself, not the shared objects it has loaded.

Comment: Have you tested that it does not return the application itself?

Comment: The application executable is actually one of the loaded shared objects. I agree it's not clear from the man page or my answer :-)